# Synonym [on-topic-definition], [scope], [offtopic]

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, offtopic, synonym-request, scope

I think these tags should be made as synonyms: [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition), [scope](/questions/tagged/scope), [offtopic](/questions/tagged/offtopic)

See also on the MSE: [What is the difference between the "scope" and the "on-topic" tags on most child metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299951/260800)

Comment: Briefly searching, i found we have both "offtopic" and "off-topic" so those are without a doubt the same. I also see that "off-topic" links/is synonym with on-topic-definition. Regarding "scope" I can think of examples of how scope is not the same as asking if something is on/off topic (i.e.: user asking help to narrow down the scope of a prospect question).

Comment: then perhaps we should make the tag less ambiguity: question-scope and site-scope. The latter which will be merged with on-topic-definition